# Using the schedule library in python to run tasks in specific intervals

Tags: python, file, documentation, schedule

I'm using the 'schedule' library to automate a task.

I don't see quite specific options here, let's say I wanna run my script Mon to Fri, every hour from 11:00 to 18:00, how do you write that?

I am writing it like this:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    f = open('model.py')
    try:
        exec(f.read())
    finally:
        f.close()

schedule.every().monday.at('11:00').do(job)
schedule.every().tuesday.at('11:00').do(job)

# ... monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday
# ... ... 11:00 12:00 13:00 14:00 15:00 16:00 17:00 18:00

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The options from the documentations are:

```
# schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
# schedule.every().hour.do(job)
# schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
# schedule.every().monday.do(job)
# schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)
# schedule.every().minute.at(":17").do(job)`
```

If I have to write it like this, there would be tons of lines in this code, I'm sure you can do this more efficiently... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I used [rrule](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#rrule-examples) from `dateutil` to make it a bit more efficient. The `rrule` let you iterate over datetime. Try the following:

```py
from dateutil import rrule
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import schedule

def job():
    f = open('model.py')
    try:
        exec(f.read())
    finally:
        f.close()

start_hour = datetime.strptime("11","%H")
end_hour = start_hour + timedelta(hours=7)

for t in rrule.rrule(rrule.HOURLY, dtstart=start_hour, until=end_hour):
    schedule.every().monday.at(t.strftime("%H:%M")).do(job)
    schedule.every().tuesday.at(t.strftime("%H:%M")).do(job)
    schedule.every().wednesday.at(t.strftime("%H:%M")).do(job)
    schedule.every().thursday.at(t.strftime("%H:%M")).do(job)
    schedule.every().friday.at(t.strftime("%H:%M")).do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```